# ubuntu 16.04, purple screen after reboot

Tags: boot, unity, grub2, vnc, mate

I was following https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/carla_headless/, and tried some commands there, and installed VGL, TurboVNC,etc.
I usually work on my vnc window, but I sometimes work on the console. With all these installations, my console used to work fine, but probably after I installed mate yesterday, I have this problem of seeing just the purple screen after boot on the console. So I uninstalled mate-desktop-environment with --purge option. Still the same. I still I can use the VNC.
I think it's to do with window manager (I want unity back). What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, during following the link above, I gave a command
`sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --use-display-device=None --virtual=1280x1024`
and this set the nvidia driver for virtual screen, with no physical display device.
So I gave the command nvidia-xconfig again and the /etc/X11/org.conf file was recovered and the problem is gone. (you can  either block some lines like I did for second trial)

```
<< /etc/X11/xorg.conf>>

.. continued ..

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "None"
    SubSection     "Display"
#        Virtual     1280 1024
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "None"
    SubSection     "Display"
#        Virtual     1280 1024
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```